# Does the fairy respawn?

Tags: magicka

I bought Magicka 2 before playing Magicka (1), and in Magicka 2 the fairy or whichever pet you choose will respawn after a certain time. I have been playing Magicka for a while now and have noticed that the fairy only seems to come back after dying and spawning at a checkpoint. Is this how the fairy works, or dies it just have a really long respawn timer?

Answer (score 3):

No, she **does not** respawn automatically after a certain period of time. The only way to get the Fairy back is to get to a checkpoint/finish a chapter...

*And don't you dare to have her sacrifice herself once again for your worthless life, you bathrobe wizard!*